# How to get terminal output to csv file in proper table format?

Tags: linux, csv, output

Suppose we run a script and want have its output stored in a csv file but in a table format, like in log we want same data to be in same column

Terminal output is like this-->

```
File searched is xyz
fie found at line number 09
"key": "name", "value": "Ramesh" 
"Key": "contact num", "value": "1234"
```

But I want output like this in csv

```
| File name | Line number | name   | contact num |
|    xyz    |    08       | Ramesh |     1234    |
```

Comment: Maybe with `csvkit` ? https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: Like @MarkSetchell suggested, the [csvlook command](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripts/csvlook.html) in the csvkit package, "Renders a CSV to the command line in a Markdown-compatible, fixed-width format".

Comment: we should directly save the output in the csv, it will be saved in the proper format,